# iPhone Difference between [(id)Object class] and object_getClassName(id Object)

Tags: iphone

can someone tell me what the difference is between  [(id)Object class] and object_getClassName(id Object) and when and why you would prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former gives you the actual class while the latter gives you the name of the class as a string.